# DevOps Linking Project Dependency from another Solution

Tags: visual-studio, devops, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm receiving a build error in DevOps for a .Net Core 3 web application using a project dependent Razor Class Library from another solution.

For the DevOps pipeline, I receive the following build solution error:

```
##[error]d:\a\1\s\consumer.app.sln.metaproj(0,0): Error MSB3202: The project file "d:\a\1\s\..\framework.app\framework.rcl\framework.rcl.csproj" was not found.
```

I have another pipeline for the framework.app project (which also uses framework.rcl as a project dependency) but because the framework.rcl project is within that solution (and the same repo), it works flawlessly.

Is there any way (preferably without nuget) to access the framework.rcl razor class library from the consumer.app pipeline?

Everything works perfect locally as the project has been added in visual studio (via Add Existing project), but obviously that linked project is not included in source control for the consumer.app solution.

Please Help :)

Answer (score 0):

I tripped over myself here. I was deep into managing project dependencies and using Azure Artifacts to do so.

However, the problem here wasn't a dependency issue. Msbuild in the Azure DevOps pipeline was simply trying to build a shared project used in the solution that wasn't available in the repo.

In Visual Studio, I simply unticked the build for the 'Release' configuration in Configuration Manager and DevOps no longer wants to build it.

I get a warning, but no error and my package reference to my Azure artifact (nuget) ensures everything wires up correctly.